# Vue-select bind v-model to save value, not label

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to VueJs (currently working on: 2.5.8) and trying to implement [vue-select](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select).

I have successfully integrated the plugin in my app and using it with:

`<v-select :options="oData" v-model="selected">`

`new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        oData: ["foo", "bar"],
        selected: null
    }
});`

This seems to work fine, but whenever I select foo or bar from the options, the `selected` contains `foo/bar` based on selected, whereas I want to store it's respective index, for ex: if `foo` is selected, the `selected` should contain `0` instead of `foo`.

Can anyone please help me to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
oData = [{label:"foo", value:"1"},{label:"bar", value:"2"}]

<v-select 

v-model="selected"

:items="oData"

item-text="label"

item-value="value"

>

</v-select>
```